# gerundetes Gesicht oder rundes Gesicht?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know if I can use "gerundetes Gesicht" in the place of "rundes Gesicht" without changing the meaning of the text below?

> Ein rundes Gesicht wirkt durch die passenden Langhaarfrisuren optisch
>   schmaler und besser proportioniert – es lohnt sich also, beim Friseur
>   und beim Stylen zu Hause auf ein paar Dinge zu achten. [Quelle](http://www.freundin.de/beauty-frisuren-fuer-lange-haare-lange-haare-beim-friseur-rundes-gesicht-diese-langhaarfrisuren-eignen-sich-196764.html).

Comment: *Gerundetes Gesicht* sounds like somebody had been seeing a [retrophrenologist](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Retrophrenology).

Comment: ....or a Mathematician ;). Hint: Most of the hits on a Google search for "gerundet" end up in a mathematical context, if you exclude dictionaries.

Comment: _rundliches Gesicht_ would work, though

Comment: @Crissov wobei ich bei "rund" an die Kopfform, bei "rundlich" an Pausbacken und etwas Übergewicht denke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Gerundet* : Participle of "runden" - i.e making something round (numbers or shapes, typically), refers to something that *has been made* round - like *abgerundete Kanten*, *gerundete* *Zahlen*

*Rund* : Adjective - refers to something that *is* round.

A face that *has been made round* (by surgery or a retrophrenologist) would be *gerundet*.

A face that was born and grew up to be round would be just *rund*.

But admittedly, even native speakers get this wrong every now and then.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't, you have to stick with 'rundes'.

```
rund(es) -> round
gerundetes -> rounded
```

Using 'gerundet' implies that the object (like a number) has been rounded, but not that it 'appears' round.